# Android physical keyboard still makes virtual keyboard show

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, android-virtual-keyboard, android-navigation

I'm working on a project where I use an 'Android Mini PC' (chinese) and connect it to the TV. The user uses their remote to navigate through the environment.

The application is fullscreen, but whenever a dialog is launched, the virtual keyboard pops up with the navigation bar, which needs to be hidden at all times. (even though I'm testing with a physical keyboard) I didn't have this problem with an older model of the Android Mini PC.

I can force the virtual keyboard off by disabling the service, but I just need it to remain hidden when a physical keyboard is present, not the entire time. (worked fine on the older model, which fried itself, thus I'm using a new model)

The second problem is the navigation bar. Even though the service is disabled, the navigation bar still shows up when the keyboard would be launched. For the project I'm working on, it's crucial the navigation bar stays of the screen. I fear the Mini PC thinks it's a tablet, which makes it harder (if not impossible) to keep the navigation bar hidden at all times.